# How can I insert Oracle SQL IF ELSE in to UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I am trying to join 3 tables and I have the following sql without IF ELSE.

```
update transaction t
set t.lid= (
select l.id from list l
inner join distance d
on l.ueid=d.ueid
inner join transaction t2
on t2.id=d.id
)
```

The only problem is the statement

```
select l.id from list l
    inner join distance d
    on l.ueid=d.ueid
    inner join transaction t2
    on t2.id=d.id
```

returns more than one value and I wasn't able to assign it to **t.gid**. With our business rule, if it returns more than one value I have to set **t.gid** to be null. How can I incorporate if else statement in this sql to return null if the inner select statement returns more than one value ? I have seen other posts on the net but they are mostly procedures or functions.

**EDIT :**

The basic idea is to update all **lid** rows on **transaction** table if **l.id** from **listing** table returns only one value (i.e after inner join with **distance** table). If multiple values are returned, I've to update it as null. So I am not totally sure if I should use only **t or t2**.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any correlation between the `t` you're updating and the subquery - is `t2` needed, and if not is this a one-off update or something you should really be doing with a view? Also some sample data and expected results might be useful. And `uid` is a reserved word, so is that really a quoted identifier?

Comment: @AlexPoole I updated my question (see Edit please). uid was a typo. It is ueid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [a case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) to check the aggregated count of values for each ID:

```
select t2.id, case when count(l.id) > 1 then null else max(l.id) end as lid
from list l
inner join distance d on l.ueid=d.ueid
inner join transaction t2 on t2.id=d.id
group by t2.id
```

And then use that as a subquery, correlating with - for example - the ID from both `transaction` tables:

```
update transaction t
set t.lid= (
  select case when count(l.id) > 1 then null else max(l.id) end as lid
  from list l
  inner join distance d on l.ueid=d.ueid
  inner join transaction t2 on t2.id=d.id
  where t2.id = t.id
  group by t2.id
)
```

where the correlation is being done with the `where t2.id = t.id` clause. Although if that is the check you're doing you probably don't really want `t2` at all:

```
update transaction t
set t.lid= (
  select case when count(l.id) > 1 then null else max(l.id) end as lid
  from list l
  inner join distance d on l.ueid=d.ueid
  where d.id = t.id
  group by d.id
)
```

correlating now with `where d.id = t.id`.

If you might get multiple instance of the *same*lid`value, and in that case still want to use that single repeated value instead of null, then you can add a`distinct` to the count:

```
update transaction t
set t.lid= (
  select case when count(distinct l.id) > 1 then null else max(l.id) end as lid
  from list l
  inner join distance d on l.ueid=d.ueid
  where d.id = t.id
  group by d.id
)
```

Untested as there is no sample data to work from, and no expected results, but hopefully aligns with your description...

Also note that this will update any existing `transaction.lid` values to null if there are no matching values in the subquery - not just when there are multiple matches. If that isn't what you want to happen then you can add a filter to restrict which rows are updated, using an `exists` clause. You could also use a `merge`, but an `update` is probably still simpler and clearer here.

Comment: this seems a neat solution for me. It has been 30 mins since the sql was running. We have 1 million rows on transaction table. Do you have a way to test this may be just for 1000 rows ? Thanks.

Comment: You can test a smaller set of rows by using where `mod(ID,100000)=0. You can easily  increase  the sample size by mod(id,10000) ...and decrease the sample size by mod(id,1000000) etc..

Comment: @zundarz An easier way is to add "where rownum < 11" (or any number you choose). This is the standard Oracle method of limiting the number of rows a SQL statement works upon. I usually use it with a select statement, so to ensure I am not "blowing smoke", I just tested it with an update statement: it worked.